# Jenkins pipeline Caught exception:java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Having minimal experience with groovy and pipeline, I am trying to migrate our code from the old DSL flow plugin written in groovy to work with the pipeline.  With some minor changes, it seems like I am able to get through most of the code except when trying to trigger a Jenkins job.  The code kinda long so I am only capturing the part where I think I am having issues.  Based on [Serializing Local Variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables) and [Pipeline CPS Method Mismatches](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/), I think it has something to do with using a CPS-transformed code like "build job" within the method. I think this is not allowed.  But I'm not sure how I can pass these values from a groovy method into a pipeline stage/steps.  I will get the NotSerializableExceptin message when it reaches the line "build job:".  Any help or pointers is appreciated - thanks!

```
@NonCPS
def func1 = { param1, param2, param3, param4 ->
try {     
    build job: jobName, parameters: [string(name: 'PARAM1', value: param1), string(name: 'PARAM2', value: param2), string(name: 'PARAM3', value: param3), string(name: 'PARAM4', value: param4)]
} catch (Exception e) {
    println "Caught exception:" + e
}

node {
....
    func1 (param1, param2, param3, param4)
....

}
```

Comment: Did you try defining func1 as a normal function "def func1(param1, ...){} and not a closure?

Comment: changing it to "def func1(param1, ...){} seems to get me to the next step but now I am getting exception:java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.ProcessImpl.  Is this due to the groovy "Process p" that I am using within a function?  I am using this since I need to run a perforce command and would like to capture the output of the command. If so, how can I change this?

Comment: Did you use @NonCPS with that function as well?

Comment: Yes, I used @NonCPS for all of the functions that I have.

Comment: It could be that you need to seperate out the parts that are actually NonCPS, since @NonCPS functions may not call CPS ones (like build). Did you have a look at this? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/

Comment: That is possible. If I move the methods inside the script { } will I still have this limitation regarding the NonCPS?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use [@NonCPS](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#use-of-pipeline-steps-fromnoncps) annotation for those function? Looks like it could solve your problem

Comment: do you think by having the "build job:" within the function is illegal?  I am thinking that "build job:" is a serialized step and not allowed within the groovy function?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure I used the build step in a function before

Comment: so can I use the "build" step within a method like below?  If not, any suggestion on how I can do this within this method or how I can pass the values back into the pipeline clause?
    
           @NonCPS
           def func1 () {
                  ....
                 build job: 'JOBNAME'
                 .....

          }